# Jquery loader gif sequential load

Tags: jquery, sequence, loader, gif

What i am trying to do is have an ajax loader gif, that shows while the images then load into the page in sequence.

so it would work like this.

ajax loader show - image fadeIn - ajax loader fadeOut - then move onto next image.

ajax loader show - image fadeIn - ajax loader fadeOut - then move onto next image.

ajax loader show - image fadeIn - ajax loader fadeOut - then move onto next image.

ajax loader show - image fadeIn - ajax loader fadeOut - then move onto next image.

Keep doing that right down the page.

Here is my code.

```
 <ul id="clients">
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_03.jpg" width="242" height="152" alt="Taylor Woodrow" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_04.jpg" width="242" height="152" alt="BG Group" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_05.jpg" width="242" height="152" alt="Canon" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_06.jpg" width="227" height="152" alt="department" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_08.jpg" width="242" height="164" alt="disney" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_09.jpg" width="218" height="164" alt="xts" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_10.jpg" width="223" height="164" alt="fisevr" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logos/clients_11.jpg" width="227" height="164" alt="hilti" /></li>
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("ul#clients li").append('<img id="show" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="fvdsv" />');
  $("ul#clients li:eq(0)").show("fast", function () {
    /* use callee so don't have to name the function */
    $(this).next("ul#clients li").fadeIn("slow", arguments.callee);

  });
```

So it kind off works but the ajax loader just shows all the time any help?

Thanks

Comment: By shows all the time do you mean it's not removed at the end and you need to figure out a way to remove it when there are no images left?

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you have id=show in img and you attach that to all images which is not proper HTML. Ids should be unique.

If you want to show the ajax gif while the image is loading and after it is loaded, show the image and hide the gif, you should use something like this:

- Add class "images" to the images you want to load first and in it add a style display:none.
- Then add the ajax gifs straight to the html after these images (or you can do it like you have done in your example).

Use the code:

```
 $('ul#clients li img.images').load(function() {
   $(this).next().fadeOut();
   $(this).fadeIn();
 } );
```